# WPF Newbie from Forms: Basic Events understanding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, event-handling

Even though late to the party, our company is finally moving slowly but surely to WPF for our desktop programming needs.

I have a few questions I was hoping this community could help me with... b/c I am finding even though I am reading all the tutorials in the world, that with WPF, there are so many different ways to approach the most basic things you used to do with Forms, that I just need a 101...
For instance...

Can anyone please enlighten a frustrated WPF newbie why this BASIC code is not working?

```
        private void BtnImport_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             //Button disabled on it's own without below routines
             BtnImport.IsEnabled = false;   
             // So does textbox which updates on it's own without below routines
             TxtTest.Text = "Started at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";

             //Bunch of routines that each run in their own loops

         }
```

When I try to disable the button and update the textbox along with those routines mentioned.. the routines run JUST FINE.. .but the button NEVER gets disabled nor does the textbox get updated?

I have a feeling I still am not understanding how WPF does things in Bindings, but I was hoping for a light bulb moment from here to just point me out WHY the basics don't work here?
Thanks~

Thank you so much. here is the XAML. @Joe I totally get that I am not using bindings, and I think that is a CORE of my confusion, if I am setting it directly, why is it not working when other routines are running after I directly set a property? (and my novice thought was that it was bindings).  In any case, as requested here is XAML code.

```
         <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FF8FB1B1" Name="AnalyticsWindow"                Loaded="AnalyticsWindow_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="74*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="429*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Height="23"   Margin="66,62,187,0" Name="TxtTime" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>


    <Button  Content="Import" Height="23"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,179,0,0" Name="BtnImport" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BtnImport_Click" Grid.Column="1" />

    <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="64,108,0,0" Name="ObjDateFrom"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Grid.Column="1" />
    <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,108,0,0" Name="ObjDateTo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Label Content="Log" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="234,28,39,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,62,0,0" Name="TxtTest" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="182" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: You're not using bindings here -- you're directly setting property values -- so your understanding of bindings isn't relevant to this problem. Are you sure this code is actually running (like, have you set a breakpoint and seen it get hit)? My first thought is that the event might not be wired up in your XAML, at which point this code wouldn't even run.

Comment: Please can you show the xaml that wires up the event and defines the `Button` and `TextBox` controls (or the code if you are not using xaml)?

Comment: Gents! thank you so much. here is the XAML. @Joe I totally get that I am not using bindings, and I think that is a CORE of my confusion, if I am setting it directly, why is it not working when other routines are running after I directly set a property? (and my novice thought was that it was bindings). XAML is in original post, I couldn't find a way to paste it in reply

Comment: aLSO @Joe... the click event is for sure running, because the routines mentioned in commenting DO run, yet the simple properties being set for button and TxtTest are NOT running when those routines are also asked to be run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what you wrote, the code is actually working, but not giving the UI 'enough time to breath' so that your changes can be rendered on the user surface.  Consider changing to this...

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => { 
            BtnImport.IsEnabled = false;
            TxtTest.Text = "Started at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        }));
```

with a symmetrical BeginInvoke at the end of your intensive processing so that the button is enabled again.  This will mitigate your problem and help you get the behaviour you are after.

I would also suggest that the parts stated as...

```
//Bunch of routines that each run in their own loops
```

...are candidates for the WPF BackgroundWorker or passing the code off to a Task<> that you can await upon.  Doing this will keep the UI responsive and let you enable/disable buttons and update text blocks in 'real-time'.

The BackgroundWorker or Task<> is the so-called 'golden solution' if the UI thread is totally starved out.  There are a zillion samples out there you can easily cut and paste into your code.  I recommend the Task<> approach because it is not reliant upon WPF namespaces.

In its simplest form, you can do this...

```
        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // lots of business processing code here
            });
```

And synch up your stuff using await...

Comment: This sounds like worth trying.. will try now.. and let you know. Thank you Garry!

Comment: All part of the service.  But 2 'r's in Garry please :)

Comment: @Garry.. I tried the BeginInvoke, and it's amazing... it still doesn't work! The other routines run just fine, but those simple button and textbox actions still don't take place... I didn't try putting the other routines in the BackGround Worker yet... I just thought to see at least if your suggestion makes the simple code run... hmm

Comment: Sir; you are a scholar and gentlemen... This DID work, HOWEVER now one slight issue. some of the routines that I am running in async backround worker process are complaining because of an error regarding scope of thread... any advice on this error? "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." This is happening on variable declarations inside routines -->inside worker. We are getting closer!

Comment: here is based on your answer the algorithm as it runs now which causes error.  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                BtnImport.IsEnabled = false;
                TxtTime.Text = "Started at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
            }));

            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(WorkerDone);

            worker.RunWorkerAsync(); Seems like my objects on the form (Main window in WPF speak :) are not accessible by the worker routines..

Comment: Yes!  That exception is a very positive development for you!  It means your strategy is working and the only remaining bit is to avoid cross-thread referencing to UI objects.  You may even remember this from the WinForms world.  To solve it in WPF, you can also use the object's Dispatcher, in the background thread.  Straight-forward, but to be fair to SO users who want to participate in cross-threading issues, you should pose a new question.  Hope that helps!

Comment: And for heaven's sake entitle your new question "WPF Cross Threading and Synchronization Problem".  That will attract lots of higher-ups to give an answer :)

Comment: If I knew how to change that title of the question I would! still working on this ... hopefully post results soon